# What's the difference between session storage and container in Zend?

Tags: php, session, zend-framework

I'm trying to learn how to use sessions with ZF2/Doctrine for a login form. [The documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.session.storage.html) lists both Container and Session Storage for accessing the SESSION variable. But which do I use? And how do I use the Session Storage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per i knowledge: 
Zend\Session\Container as SessionContainer; Container extends of ArrayObject means to you can easily iterate through properties and read/write them, e.g.

```
use Zend\Session\Container as SessionContainer;
$this->session = new SessionContainer('post');
$this->session->post_id = 1;
var_dump($this->session->post_id);
```

Session Storage:

```html
use Zend\Session\Storage\ArrayStorage;
use Zend\Session\SessionManager;

$populateStorage = array('foo' => 'bar');
$storage         = new ArrayStorage($populateStorage);
$manager         = new SessionManager();
$manager->setStorage($storage);
var_dump($manager->getStorage());
```